# Image does not upload carriewave / simple_form / Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, simple-form

When I try to create new record image doesn't upload but when I try to edit everything working fine. No errors, after create I have nil in DB after Update I have a link to a picture and everything fine. What I did wrong? Before I used form_for and everything was working fine, then I change form_for to simple_form. Maybe problem here?

Controller:

```
def create

    #byebug
      @bar = current_user.bars.new(bar_params)
    if @bar.save
      UserMailer.admin_verify_email(@bar.id).deliver_now
      flash[:success] = t(".bar_created_successfully")

      # if admin_verified add bar to the search bos
      if @bar.admin_verified
        Barsearchsuggestion.index_bar(@bar)
        redirect_to bars_path(my_bar: true)
      else
        redirect_to bar_status_user_path(current_user)
      end

    else
      flash.now[:alert] = @bar.errors.full_messages
      render 'users/add_bar'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @bar = Bar.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @bar = Bar.find(params[:id])

    if @bar.update_attributes(bar_params)
      flash[:success] = "Bar updated."
      redirect_to bar_status_user_path(current_user)
    else
      flash.now[:error] = I18n.t("simple_form.error_notification.default_message")
      # flash[:error] = @bar.errors.to_array
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

 private

  def bar_params

   params.require(:bar).permit!

  end
```

View:

```
=simple_form_for(@bar) do |f|

.form-group

      = f.label :profile_picture
      = t(".profile_picture_ext_html")
      %br
      = image_tag f.object.profile_picture.bar_detail.url
      = f.file_field :profile_picture, class: 'form-control'
```

Model:

```
mount_uploader :profile_picture, BarPictureUploader
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to permit the `profile_picture` parameter like this:

```
def bar_params
  params.require(:bar).permit(:profile_picture)
end
```

Comment: But why Update action works fine with this "(params.require(:bar).permit!)"? I have about 50 fields in my form. All of them stored in DB successfuly only image isn't saved ? Image can be stored only when perform update action

Comment: Before I used form_for and everything was working fine, then I change form_for to simple_form. Maybe problem here

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `multipart: true` in your form

Comment: Hi Asalgan. It didn't help.

Comment: While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, an answer really needs to demonstrate the solution.  Please [edit] to provide example code to show what you mean. Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead.